# How to start/stop a service from an activity?

Tags: android

I have a toggle button in my main activity. I want a service to start when the toggle button is on and stop when it is off. The activity may be closed at any time. I want the activity to 'remember' the service it had started before the activity was closed and the activity should be able to close this service it had started on its previous run.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) first, then use these guys to control it: [startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) and [stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29). About remember, you can use static variable to check the status of service, and change it on onCreate and onDestroy of your service, it's like one of the solutions.